# Unable to get debug signature key while setting up SDK/Eclipse on OSX

Tags: android

I installed the Android SDK and Eclipse on OSX.  When I check my ~/.android folder there is no debug.keystore.  My understanding though is that it gets created when you run, build, or clean.  I create a simple HelloWorld project and set up my run configurations.  When I try to run I see the following error:

Error generating final archive: Unable to get debug signature key   HelloAndroid        Unknown Android Packaging Problem

I then see that the debug.keystore still isn't created.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For anyone else out there that this happens to... it was a permissions problem on the .android folder.  For some reason I didn't have write access to the folder and subfolders set.

Answer (score 2):

I too had the error

> Error generating final archive: Unable to get debug signature key

It seemed I did not have a default keystore.  So I created one.

It still didn't work even though I noticed in my Eclipse `Preferences` in `Android > Build` that my default keystore was recognized.

When I chose it AGAIN as my `custom` keystore, I got an error saying

> can't find debug key in keystore

which then brought to my attention although I created the *key store*, I had not created the *debug key* that is contained within.

I went back to my terminal application and entered:

```
keytool -keygen -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android
```

from within my `.android` directory, and all was good.

[image: error in UI]

Macintosh OSX 10.8.2 Mountain Lion, Eclipse v3.7.2 Juno Android

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and Jody G's fix pointed me in the right direction. In my case, debug.keystore existed, but it was a symlink pointing to a file that had been deleted. Getting rid of the symlink forced Eclipse to regenerate the file.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have the following:

- keystore is in .android/debug.keystore and is readable
- .android is writtable
- keystore password is "android"
- key alias is androiddebugkey
- no password on the key (to remove a password on a key, set the password to the same password as the keystore itself, here: "android").